# Картинки в один ряд по горизонтали

Tags: html, css, изображения

Изображения одинакового размера, но не становятся в один ряд по горизонтали

```
<div class = "home-photo">
                <div class = "advantages" >
                    <div class = "photos">
                        <img src="images/1.jpeg" alt="" />
                        <h2>Ress</h2>
                        <p>Выбирая средство, которое увлажнит руки, обязательно нужно подумать о том, какой эффект хочется получить. Так, например, если кожа рук чувствительна и требует профессионального ухода, понадобится крем с минимумом отдушек, например, Urea 5% Hand Cream (frei öl)</p>
                        <img src="images/2.jpeg" alt="" />
                        <h2>Ress</h2>
                        <p>Выбирая средство, которое увлажнит руки, обязательно нужно подумать о том, какой эффект хочется получить. Так, например, если кожа рук чувствительна и требует профессионального ухода, понадобится крем с минимумом отдушек, например, Urea 5% Hand Cream (frei öl)</p>
                        <img src="images/3.jpeg" alt="" />
                        <h2>Ress</h2>
                        <p>Выбирая средство, которое увлажнит руки, обязательно нужно подумать о том, какой эффект хочется получить. Так, например, если кожа рук чувствительна и требует профессионального ухода, понадобится крем с минимумом отдушек, например, Urea 5% Hand Cream (frei öl)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

---

```
.home-photo
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.advantages
{
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.photos
{
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы не добавили в блок .advantages блоки .photos - в вашем примере он один.

```
  <div class = "home-photo">
    <div class = "advantages" >
      <div class = "photos">
        <img src="images/1.jpeg" alt="" />
        <h2>Ress</h2>
        <p>Выбирая средство, которое увлажнит руки, обязательно нужно подумать о том, какой эффект хочется получить. Так, например, если кожа рук чувствительна и требует профессионального ухода, понадобится крем с минимумом отдушек, например, Urea 5% Hand Cream (frei öl)</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "photos">
        <img src="images/2.jpeg" alt="" />
        <h2>Ress</h2>
        <p>Выбирая средство, которое увлажнит руки, обязательно нужно подумать о том, какой эффект хочется получить. Так, например, если кожа рук чувствительна и требует профессионального ухода, понадобится крем с минимумом отдушек, например, Urea 5% Hand Cream (frei öl)</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "photos">
        <img src="images/3.jpeg" alt="" />
        <h2>Ress</h2>
        <p>Выбирая средство, которое увлажнит руки, обязательно нужно подумать о том, какой эффект хочется получить. Так, например, если кожа рук чувствительна и требует профессионального ухода, понадобится крем с минимумом отдушек, например, Urea 5% Hand Cream (frei öl)</p>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/syntaxys/8cyngmef/)

Comment: Большое спасибо)